# parse array in javascript android?

Tags: javascript, android, arrays, webview

i have problem with my app,I use webview in this case,I successfull pass array from java to javascript and show array like this.

```
{recLokUserlain:[{"urut":"8","id_a":"acer@acer.com","waktu":"2013-12-26 11:21:24","latitude":"-7.97431333333333","longitude":"112.659455","tempat":"malang isi sendiri","sts_ol":"0","waktu_update":"2014-02-05 14:37:19"},{"urut":"7","id_a":"ace@ace.com","waktu":"2013-12-26 17:34:46","latitude":"-7.89431333333333","longitude":"112.658455","tempat":"malaang juga","sts_ol":"1","waktu_update":"2014-02-13 11:32:25"}]}
```

My problem is, how i parse the array to get string?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you pass your array as:

```
{"recLokUserlain":[{"urut":"8","id_a":"acer@acer.com","waktu":"2013-12-26 11:21:24","latitude":"-7.97431333333333","longitude":"112.659455","tempat":"malang isi sendiri","sts_ol":"0","waktu_update":"2014-02-05 14:37:19"},{"urut":"7","id_a":"ace@ace.com","waktu":"2013-12-26 17:34:46","latitude":"-7.89431333333333","longitude":"112.658455","tempat":"malaang juga","sts_ol":"1","waktu_update":"2014-02-13 11:32:25"}]}
```

you should be able to use `JSON.parse()` to turn the string containing the above into a JavaScript array with objects inside.

Comment: how to use JSON.parse() in javascript? would you like to show me the way?